# Pandas User Defined Function (UDF) - Is it possible to return a boolean?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to write a function as a Pandas UDF, that would check if any element of a string array starts with a particular value. The result i'm looking for would be something like this :

```
df.filter(list_contains(val, df.stringArray_column)).show()
```

The function list_contains would return **True** on every row where any element of df.stringArray starts with val.

Just an example:

```
df = spark.read.csv(path)
display(df.filter(list_contains('50', df.stringArray_column)))
```

This code above would display every row of df where an element of the stringArray column starts with 50.

I have written a function in python, which is very slow

```
    def list_contains(val):
    # Perfom what ListContains generated
  def list_contains_udf(column_list):
    for element in column_list:
      if element.startswith(val):
        return True
    return False
  return udf(list_contains_udf, BooleanType())
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Here is some sample Data and also an output example that i'm looking for:

```
df.LIST: ["408000","641100"]
         ["633400","641100"]
         ["633400","791100"]
         ["633400","408100"]
         ["633400","641100"]
         ["408110","641230"]
         ["633400","647200"]

display(df.select('LIST').filter(list_contains('408')(df.LIST)))

output: LIST
        ["408000","641100"]
        ["633400","408100"]
        ["408110","641230"]
```

Comment: Could you post example data and expected result?

Comment: for spark 2.4+, use sparksql built-in function *exists*: `df.filter('exists(stringArray_column, x -> left(x,3)="408")').show()`, link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#exists:

Comment: @jxc damn, that's a pretty concise one liner solution.

Comment: Thank you for this useful comment @jxc , where can i find more complex 'exists' examples ?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**:

It's possible to do that without an UDF if we assume arrays are of same length. Let's try the following.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('prefix_finder').getOrCreate()

# sample data creation
my_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('scooby', ['cartoon', 'kidfriendly']),
     ('batman', ['dark', 'cars']),
     ('meshuggah', ['heavy', 'dark']),
     ('guthrie', ['god', 'guitar'])
     ]
    , schema=('character', 'tags'))
```

The dataframe `my_df` would look like following:

```
+---------+----------------------+
|character|tags                  |
+---------+----------------------+
|scooby   |[cartoon, kidfriendly]|
|batman   |[dark, cars]          |
|meshuggah|[heavy, dark]         |
|guthrie  |[god, guitar]         |
+---------+----------------------+
```

If we're searching for the prefix *car*, only the 1st and 2nd row should be returned, because *car* is a prefix of *cartoon* and *cars*.

Here comes the native spark operations to achieve that.

```
num_items_in_arr = 2 # this was the assumption
prefix = 'car'

my_df2 = my_df.select(col('character'), col('tags'), *(col('tags').getItem(i).alias(f'tag{i}') for i in range(num_items_in_arr)))
```

The dataframe `my_df2` would look like:

```
+---------+----------------------+-------+-----------+
|character|tags                  |tag0   |tag1       |
+---------+----------------------+-------+-----------+
|scooby   |[cartoon, kidfriendly]|cartoon|kidfriendly|
|batman   |[dark, cars]          |dark   |cars       |
|meshuggah|[insane, heavy]       |insane |heavy      |
|guthrie  |[god, guitar]         |god    |guitar     |
+---------+----------------------+-------+-----------+
```

Let's create a column *concat_tags* on `my_df2`, which we're going to use for regex match.

```
cols_of_interest = [f'tag{i}' for i in range(num_items_in_arr)]

for idx, col_name in enumerate(cols_of_interest):
    my_df2 = my_df2.withColumn(col_name, f.substring(col_name, 1, prefix_len))

    if idx == 0:
        my_df2 = my_df2.withColumn(col_name, f.concat(lit("("), col_name, lit(".*")))
    elif idx == len(cols_to_update_concat) - 1:
        my_df2 = my_df2.withColumn(col_name, f.concat(col_name, lit(".*)")))
    else:
        my_df2 = my_df2.withColumn(col_name, f.concat(col_name, lit(".*")))

my_df3 = my_df2.withColumn('concat_tags', f.concat_ws('|', *cols_of_interest)).drop(*cols_of_interest)
```

`my_df3` is like the following:

```
+---------+----------------------+-------------+
|character|tags                  |concat_tags  |
+---------+----------------------+-------------+
|scooby   |[cartoon, kidfriendly]|(car.*|kid.*)|
|batman   |[dark, cars]          |(dar.*|car.*)|
|meshuggah|[insane, heavy]       |(ins.*|hea.*)|
|guthrie  |[god, guitar]         |(god.*|gui.*)|
+---------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Now we need to apply regex mathing on the column *concat_tags*.

```
my_df4 = my_df3.withColumn('matched', f.expr(r"regexp_extract(prefix, concat_tags, 0)"))
```

The result look like this:

```
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------+
|character|tags                  |concat_tags  |matched|
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------+
|scooby   |[cartoon, kidfriendly]|(car.*|kid.*)|car    |
|batman   |[dark, cars]          |(dar.*|car.*)|car    |
|meshuggah|[insane, heavy]       |(ins.*|hea.*)|       |
|guthrie  |[god, guitar]         |(god.*|gui.*)|       |
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------+
```

A little bit of cleanup.

```
my_df5 = my_df4.filter(my_df4.matched != "").drop('concat_tags', 'matched')
```

And here we are, with the final dataframe:

```
+---------+----------------------+
|character|tags                  |
+---------+----------------------+
|scooby   |[cartoon, kidfriendly]|
|batman   |[dark, cars]          |
+---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: The fact is I really need the 'starting with' feature in my function.

Comment: @Epicol with the assumption that all arrays are of same length, it's doable. Please check my updated answer.